# GIT, SVN, Mercurial and Bazaar packages available to install (GUI & Terminal)

Tags: gui, git, svn, bazaar, mercurial

What packages are available in Ubuntu to use the following distributed version control systems via Terminal or GUI?

- GIT
- SVN
- Mercurial
- Bazaar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, there's:

- `git-all` which gives you *all* the git packages [editor's note: do not attempt to install `git-all` in 16.04 or later, as it breaks with `systemd`] (or, if you want to get *just* the core git packages (cli only, as this skips the GUI tool) `git-core`. See also: [Is there a GUI client for Git?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227554/what-are-some-gui-clients-for-git)
- `subversion` as for a GUI there are [several projects which are designed as a front end to Subversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Subversion_clients)
- `bazaar` for a GUI there is `bzr-explorer` See also: [What is Bazaar and how do I use it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93859/what-is-bazaar-and-how-do-i-use-it/109426#109426)
- `mercurial` and here is a list of [Mercurial GUI tools](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/OtherTools#Graphical_user_interfaces)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Should install git on your system.