# Is there a graphical git commit application to show diffs and set a commit message?

Tags: software-recommendation, git

As part of my work I regularly commit to git. I have a fabric script that does an interactive commit: `git commit -a` which shows me which files have changed in nano and then lets me write a commit message.

The problem with this flow is sometimes I need to know *what changes* I've made inside a file. I was doing a ton of stuff at 3am this morning and I can't for the life of me remember what I was doing. I have to manually `git diff` to see the changes.

Is there a graphical application that can help me out here? It still needs to be scripted from fabric but in a perfect world it would be a textbox, a list of changed files and a meld-like window showing diffs based on the file I selected. Does such a glorious thing exist?

Comment: Could we make this a ***one-application-per-answer*** kind of answer?

Comment: Are you interested in full IDEs that include this functionality among tons of others, or only in stand alone programs?.

Comment: This is certainly related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/227554/best-gui-client-for-git but I'm really just after a dialogue that can show me the current diff (broken down by file) that also allows me to set a commit message. `git citool` is more than functional enough but it looks worse than a foot.

Comment: It seems that [giggle](https://live.gnome.org/giggle) can show uncommited changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I normally just use `git gui`.  It shows the list staged and unstaged changed files, and shows their diffs, and lets you selectively stage hunks, add a log message, and commit.  Even has a nice knob to amend the last commit instead.

Answer (score 3):

The [git-gui](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gui.html) package has a `citool` extension for git that seems to have this sole goal in mind.

```
sudo apt-get install git-gui
# make some changes in your branch
git citool
```

It is as ugly as sin in KDE though and there's no schmancy meld-diff. So I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 2):

Plenty of choices and suggestions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516720/git-gui-client-for-linux

I don't use git so don't have an opinion.