# how to download git on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: gnome-terminal, git, github

whenever i type apt-get install git then it show error...
error displayed by terminal is

```
 yogesh@yogesh-dell:~$ apt-get install git
    E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
    E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Comment: sudo apt-get install git

Comment: @Pilot6 WRONG! The two error messages:  from the one you referenced: `E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11 Resource temporarily unavailable)` and from this one `(13: Permission denied)` have both a different error code (11 != 13) but different messages. They are different errors.

Comment: @waltinator I agree.

Answer (score 2):

The error messages tells you exactly what is wrong: `E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?`.

Either use the Software Center, or the `sudo` command. Read `man sudo`, then try:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Comment: how to solve the lock administration directory problem

Comment: The directory `/var/lib/dpkg` is writable (so one can create `lock`) only by `root`. It, too, will be  resolved correctly by my  by either half of my answer.

Comment: i tried sudo too . but it wasn't able to downloaded git terminal. sudo showed authentication problem. at last showed successfully installed but there isn't any git terminal in my lappy

Comment: What is a "git terminal"? What do the terminal commands `type -p git`, `man git` and `dpkg -L git` show?

Comment: /usr/bin/git
shown by first command

Comment: Therefore you have installed `git`. Now go search the internet for git How-To, and do `man -k git` and read those `man` pages.

Comment: To use the `git` client, read `man git`, `man git-clone` and other pages to find out what you need - genrally you can use the `git` command in the terminal etc, you don't need a special terminal for it. If you are using a git based SCM, they may have documentation which will tell you how to use `git` as well - e.g. https://help.github.com/ . There are also GUI clients available: http://askubuntu.com/q/227554/178596

Comment: BTW, "sudo showed authentication problem" can be only seen as "I mistyped my password" (happens to us all), but when that happens, `sudo` does not do anything, so reporting it does not help.