# Which is the best git client for linux?

Tags: programming, git, development, github, version-control

I am moving out of a windows enviroment where i used [Tortoise Git](https://tortoisegit.org/). I heard linux git clients are pretty poor... can you guys help me finding a good one?

Comment: Of course this is a matter of opinion, but Ive heard good things about SmartGit and GitKraken.

Comment: Alternativeto.net is always a good site to help answer this type of question: http://alternativeto.net/software/tortoisegit/?platform=linux

Comment: without mentioning what you consider a git client needs to be good this is a matter of opinion.

Comment: i installed SmartGit, looked pretty good

Comment: This question has more answers here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/227554/what-are-some-gui-clients-for-git

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would recommend GitKraken because it is pretty polished, but it is closed-source.

Comment: Another vote for GitKraken. I just switched to it recently. It is beautifully designed and usable. And integrates with GitFlow nicely. I tried some other Linux git GUIs and they were ugly as heck, and their missing features kept leading me back to command line.

Comment: This looks amazing O_O

Comment: Downloaded and installed today. Very nice and polished, addictive gui. But the fact that it's an electron app made me uneasy, because I'm among those users who are low in RAM.

Comment: I've had a lot of troubles with GitKraken. It's nice and pretty, but it isn't stable or supportive of all features.

Comment: Not only it is closed-source, but it is only free (as in beer) for non-commercial use.  So be sure that you have a proper licence if using it for commercial use.

Comment: Not good for local network, it needs Internet and an account to use it

Answer (score 6):

I use command line but two very nice eye candy GUIs here:

http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/

http://www.collab.net/products/giteye

But you should really learn to use git in command line. It will pay off.

Comment: I installed SmartGit and used it a bit. It looks nice and does have nice integration with BitBucket and GitHub. thanks alot mate.

Comment: GitKraken needs an internet connection and an account to connect to use it, not good for local Intranet. GitExtension too complicate to install on Linux. gitg needs a lot of additional libs to compile , stops at ./configure. So, GitEye is the one that needs nothing to run, download, uncmpress and run :), good job